# anyone knows the legacy between "home screen folders" and apps?

Tags: android

I wanna know for each "home screen folder"(created by the user), which apps are in.
Or, for a given app, I wanna know in which "home screen folder(s)" is contained.
Thanks in advance for hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are talking about the icons in the launcher? Then, the answer will depend on the launcher being used, and most probably there is no method for most (if not all) of them.

Comment: I'm not sure they are launcher dependant. Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/live-folders.html

Comment: @emme OK I understand your question now. Would you be creating those folders in your app?

Comment: No, I wanna loop through each folder on the device(folders enumeration) and look into them for any app("app shortcut").

Comment: Then I stand with my first answer: it will depend on the launcher. If you know the `Intent` for the `LiveFolders` you can use `getData()` to retrieve the URI for the `ContentProvider` with that info. I do not know how far you will get with this approach, though.

Comment: Or for each app, ask this question "Am I realted to one or more folders?" And collect the related folders for that app

Comment: Probably you are right Aleadam, but I'm not 100% sure, I want to investigate a little bit

Comment: @emme sure. Let me know if you find anything different